# Package installation failure when trying to upgrade Python by using Chocolatey

Tags: windows, installation, cmd, package, chocolatey

I tried to upgrade python through Chocolatey because I had a problem with VScode, VScode doesn't recognize python but I have it installed on my pc. The problem is that when Chocolatey asked me about if I want to run all the script to install the files, I accidently put N and enter and one of the packages didn't installed, is there something I should do? Because I think this could be a problem in the future but I don't really know, the message is the following:

Chocolatey upgraded 12/13 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Upgraded:

- chocolatey-compatibility.extension v1.0.0
- chocolatey-core.extension v1.4.0
- chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension v1.0.5
- KB2919442 v1.0.20160915
- KB2999226 v1.0.20181019
- KB3033929 v1.0.5
- KB3035131 v1.0.3
- python v3.11.5
- python3 v3.11.5
- python311 v3.11.5
- vcredist140 v14.36.32532
- vcredist2015 v14.0.24215.20170201

Packages requiring reboot:

- vcredist140 (exit code 3010)

The recent package changes indicate a reboot is necessary.
Please reboot at your earliest convenience.

Failures

- KB2919355 - User canceled powershell portion of installation for 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\KB2919355\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
  Specify -n to skip automated script actions.

C:\Windows\System32>choco upgrade python
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
python
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
python v3.11.5 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

I tried:

- Searching for help by looking at the exit code on Google.
- Tried to run again the upgrade.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running a modern operating system (ie. an up-to-date Windows 10) that failed package isn't an issue.

However, to make everything normalized on your system run `choco install KB2919355`.

Note that the failing package would have made no difference to installing / running Python.